# AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/html/www/html] does not exist

Tags: apache2

when I do

```
cd /etc/apache2/
apache2ctl configtest
```

I get this:

> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/html/www/html] does not exist

Where can I find that line, so I can change it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's just a warning not an error, and you can ignore it. It's happened if you define `DocumentRoot` in the virtual host to not existed path. If you want to remove that warning, just find the virtualhost that point to that directory. Usually `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` contain like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

just change `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to the correct path, or just remove that virtualhost.